# Function linear combinations of coordinates.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, operator-theory

Consider the vectors $a=(a_1,a_2),b=(b_1,b_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$. I am looking for functions $C:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$C(a+kb)=C(a_1,a_2)+kC(a_1,b_2)+kC(b_1,a_2)+k^2C(b_1,b_2)$

Monomials, for example, satisfy this property. In general in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $C(a)=A\Pi_{i=1}^n a_i$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the property. The trivial case $C(a)=0$ is included. I came across this function as an attempt to generalize the behavior of a monomial and wanted to see other functions. Also, there is a combinatoric aspect when looking at the coordinates which reminds me to the determinant defined as permutations, but this is not the exact case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $(0,0) = (0, 0) + k(0, 0)$ for any $k$:
$$C(0, 0) = (1 + k)^2 C(0, 0) \implies C(0, 0) = 0.$$
Using $(x,0) = (0, 0) + x(1, 0)$:
$$C(x, 0) = 0 + x \times 0 + x C(1, 0) + x^2 C(1, 0) = x(1 + x) C(1,0) .$$
Setting $x = 1$, $C(1, 0) = 0$, so $C(x, 0) = 0$ for all $x$.
Similarly, $C(0, y) = 0$ for all $y$.
Now, using $(1, y) = (1, 0) + y(0, 1)$:
$$C(1, y) = C(1, 0) + y C(1, 1) + y C(0, 0) + y^2 C(0, 1) = y C(1, 1).$$
Finally, using $(x, y) = (0, y) + x(1, 0)$:
$$C(x, y) = C(0, y) + x C(0, 0) + x C(1, y) + y^2 C(1, 0) = x C(1, y) = xy C(1, 1).$$
So any such $C$ is of the form $C(x, y) = a xy$ for some fixed $a = C(1, 1)$.

I leave it to you to generalize this to $\mathbb{R}^n$.